# Promise.all in node v12 and v14

Tags: node.js, promise

Currently I'm working on a feature and found out this "issue".
Here is my piece of code:

```
 const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'hoangvu',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'hoangvu',
    password: 'hoangvu',
    port: 5432,
    query_timeout: 10000
  });

  const promiseArray = [updateTask(pool)];

  console.log(2);
  Promise.all(promiseArray)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(1);
      pool.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

My **updateTask**:

```
  async function updateTask(pool) {
  console.log(3);
  const client = await pool.connect().catch(err => {
    throw err;
  });

  await client.query('BEGIN');
  //do stuff with client
  await client.query('COMMIT');
  return 1;
}
```

If I switch to node v12.20.1, it will log **2** then **1**. But if I switch to node v14.16.0, it does not run to **.then()** part which mean it only log **2**.
I'm still researching but if there is anyone know about this "issue" please let me know. Thank you.

ps: I found out that there is something wrong this part

```
const client = await pool.connect().catch(err => {
    throw err;
});
console.log(4);
```

I'm using pg v8.5.1 and it does not reach log 4.

Comment: What does `updateTask` return? If it's a promise, I'd first isolate and figure out whether `updateTask(pool, milestone)` resolves under both versions of Node.

Comment: This is likely an implementation issue not an issue with node itself. I would triple check that you get those behaviours again. If it is the case, then the issue is in updateTask so you'll need to post that too.

Comment: I edited my post, please take a look

Comment: you don't get any errors?

Comment: Yes, there is no error thrown

Comment: Hi, maybe I found the cause but I still wonder why there is no err be thrown

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the root cause is the [pg](https://node-postgres.com/), the connection keep being timeout. So I switch to its related module [pg-pool](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master/packages/pg-pool). And everything work well.